# unique_ptr compiler error because of importing codes from VS2013 preview to VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, firebreath, visual-studio-2013

I have used the std::unique_ptr in my previous codes in Visual studio 2013 preview, and I don't have the problems there. For my recent project case, it is compiler error less in debugging in visual studio 2012. So now I only got the following errors

This is the line that having the issue:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> classHolder;
```

The following are what the compiler says

- 'unique_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'
- syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
- missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
  default-int
- unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Any thought on how can I resolve this issue?

**Sample:**

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include "JSAPIAuto.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

#ifndef H_CLASSHAVINGPROB
#define H_CLASSHAVINGPROB

class ClassHavingProb : public FB::JSAPIAuto //ClassHavingProb: this is the wrapper class if you are familiar with FireBreath(C++ to Javascript)
{
public:
    ClassHavingProb()
    {
        obj = std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(1));
//MyClass: this is the class reponsible for the functionalities, I've used unique_ptr so that class lifecycle will not be very problematic. If I used a regular pointer the class is not properly dismissed.
        //Some more init codes here
    }

    ~ClassHavingProb() {
        obj.release(); //the class must be dismissed
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> obj;
};

#endif // H_CLASSHAVINGPROB
```

Comment: did you #include <memory> ?

Comment: yep, memory is include in the header file

Comment: Present a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The obj is used as helper class.

Comment: Why are you calling `obj.release()` in the destructor?  That's a memory leak.  The whole point of smart pointers is that you don't have to manage them manually like that.  They take care of their own cleanup.  And this isn't a complete example.

Comment: Make sure the compiler is set up to use the C++11 standard.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is using the C++11 standard and it is still have the bug

Answer (score 1):

Well, since FireBreath has to run on older browsers that don't have the C++11 standard I don't know how to fix the issue you're describing directly, but you could just use a boost scoped_ptr type instead of unique_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem in VS 2013 update 4, I just wrote down

```
 using namespace std;
```

and it compiled!
I had included `<memory>` and used `std::unique_ptr<>` before trying the using statement (just like you did), and that generated the errors like those you got there.
However when I tried using the `using namespace std;`things got resolved!
thought this might help some one